# Can't find database in DDMS

Tags: android

I am following on this tutorial http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/how-to-insert-data-in-to-a-sqlite-database-in-android/, however,
when I tried, I couldn't  find my database in the DDMS.
Why is this so?

I'm not sure if it is the code problem, however, there's no eror log.
This is my code

AndroidDBHelper.java

```
public class AndroidOpenDbHelper extends  SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database attributes
            public static final String DB_NAME = "myDB";
            public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
            // Table attributes
            public static final String TABLE_NAME_LOG = "fuelLog";
            public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
            public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
            public static final String KEY_PRICE = "fuelprice";
            public static final String KEY_FUEL = "fuelpump";
            public static final String KEY_COST = "tcost";
            public static final String KEY_ODM = "odometer";
            public static final String KEY_CON = "fcon";

            public AndroidOpenDbHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            }
            // Called when the database is created for the first time. 
            //This is where the creation of tables and the initial population of the tables should happen.


            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // We need to check whether table that we are going to create is already exists.
                //Because this method get executed every time we created an object of this class. 
                //"create table if not exists TABLE_NAME ( BaseColumns._ID integer primary key autoincrement, FIRST_COLUMN_NAME text not null, SECOND_COLUMN_NAME integer not null);"
                String SQL_createTable = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME_LOG + " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                                                        + KEY_DATE + " text not null, "
                                                                        + KEY_PRICE + " text not null, "
                                                                        + KEY_FUEL + " text not null, "
                                                                        + KEY_COST + " text not null, "
                                                                        + KEY_ODM + " text not null, "
                                                                        + KEY_CON + " text not null);";
                // Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.
                db.execSQL(SQL_createTable);

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if(oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2){
                        // Upgrade the database
                    }       
                }
            }
```

fuelLogPojo.java

```
public class fuelLogPojo {
     private String date;
     private String price;
     private String pump;
     private String cost;
     private String odometer;
     private String fcon;


     public String getdate() {
             return date;
     }
     public void setdate(String date) {
             this.date = date;
     }

     public String getprice() {
             return price;
     }
     public void setprice(String price) {
             this.price = price;
     }

     public String getpump() {
             return pump;
     }
     public void setpump(String pump) {
             this.pump = pump;
     }

     public String getcost() {
         return cost;
 }
 public void setcost(String cost) {
         this.cost = cost;
 }

 public String getodometer() {
     return odometer;
}
public void setodometer(String odometer) {
     this.odometer = odometer;
}

public String getfcon() {
  return fcon;
}
public void setfcon(String fcon) {
  this.fcon = fcon;
}
}
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // TableLayout tablelayout_Log = null;
    Button saveButton = null;
    Button cancelButton = null;
   // Button searchButton = null;
    static EditText dateEdit; 
    EditText priceEdit;
    EditText pumpEdit;
    TextView costView;
    EditText odometerEdit;
    TextView fconView;
     TextWatcher textWatcher;
     String priceEditStr ="",pumpEditStr="";
     String  odmEditStr = "";
     String lastOdm = "";

double result;
double resultCon;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;


private ArrayList fuelLogArrayList;

    public boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        costView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tcost);
        dateEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
        priceEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelprice);
        pumpEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelpump);
        odometerEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.odometer);
        fconView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fcon);
        fuelLogArrayList = new ArrayList();

       // DBAdapter dbAdaptor = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
       // lastOdm = dbAdaptor.getLastOdometer();
//Check that your database is enable to fetch the value or not? 
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+lastOdm,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        dateEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });


           priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                        priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                   if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                        pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                  if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                  {
                    result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                    costView.setText(" "+result);
                  }

               }
           });

           pumpEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                   if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                   if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                      {
                        result = Double.parseDouble(priceEditStr) * Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                        costView.setText(" "+result);
                      }

               }
           });







           odometerEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

               }



               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it

                   if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                       odmEditStr = odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                  if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !lastOdm.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null) && !lastOdm.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(" "))
                     {

                       resultCon = Double.parseDouble(odmEditStr) / Double.parseDouble(pumpEditStr);              
                       fconView.setText(" "+resultCon);
                     }

               }
           });

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.cancelBTN){
            finish();
        }else if(v.getId() == R.id.saveBTN){
            // Get the values provided by the user via the UI


             String date = dateEdit.getText().toString();
             String price = priceEdit.getText().toString();
             String pump = pumpEdit.getText().toString();
             String tcost = costView.getText().toString();
             String odometer = odometerEdit.getText().toString();
             String fcon = fconView.getText().toString();


            // Pass above values to the setter methods in POJO class
             fuelLogPojo fuelLogPojoObj = new fuelLogPojo();
             fuelLogPojoObj.setdate(date);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setprice(price);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setpump(pump);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setcost(tcost);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setodometer(odometer);
             fuelLogPojoObj.setfcon(fcon);
            // Add an undergraduate with his all details to a ArrayList
             fuelLogArrayList.add(fuelLogPojoObj);

            // Inserting undergraduate details to the database is doing in a separate method
            insertLog(fuelLogPojoObj);

            // Release from the existing UI and go back to the previous UI
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void insertLog(fuelLogPojo fuelLogPojoObj) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // First we have to open our DbHelper class by creating a new object of that
        AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

        // Then we need to get a writable SQLite database, because we are going to insert some values
        // SQLiteDatabase has methods to create, delete, execute SQL commands, and perform other common database management tasks.
        SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj.getWritableDatabase();

        // ContentValues class is used to store a set of values that the ContentResolver can process.
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        // Get values from the POJO class and passing them to the ContentValues class
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_DATE, fuelLogPojoObj.getdate());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PRICE, fuelLogPojoObj.getprice());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_FUEL, fuelLogPojoObj.getpump());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_COST, fuelLogPojoObj.getcost());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ODM, fuelLogPojoObj.getodometer());
        contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_CON, fuelLogPojoObj.getfcon());

        // Now we can insert the data in to relevant table
        // I am going pass the id value, which is going to change because of our insert method, to a long variable to show in Toast
        long affectedColumnId = sqliteDatabase.insert(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, null, contentValues);

        // It is a good practice to close the database connections after you have done with it
        sqliteDatabase.close();

        // I am not going to do the retrieve part in this post. So this is just a notification for satisfaction ;-)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Values inserted column ID is :" + affectedColumnId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        





    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        public EditText editText;
        DatePicker dpResult;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (EditSessionActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        dateEdit.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
        // set selected date into datepicker also
}}}
```

Comment: Are you testing this in device or emulator ?

Comment: I am testing it in emulator

Comment: Where you are checking for database ? You have to create an instance of `AndroidOpenDbHelper` in  your activity then only database will be created.

Comment: Ok, have you select the respective emulator from device ?

Comment: @Vigbyor yes, but there's nothing..

Comment: select your device in DDMS and then look into /data/data/your.app.name/databases

Comment: What do you mean by `nothing` ?

Comment: @Vigbyor there's only cache and lib. there's no database

Comment: @Chloe, can you see your package in DDMS ?

Comment: @Tobor as mention, I couldn't find database

Comment: @Vigbyor I could only see my apps name

Comment: @Vigbyor i suspect that my insert button having problem. I did a toast , when I click, the toast message isn't shown. could you help me take a look at my code?

Comment: What do you see when you expands its ?

Comment: @Vigbyor cache and lib

Comment: @Chloe, check your code properly, You have only declared your Button variables, but never initialized them neighter add them to OnClickListener :P :P :P

Comment: @Vigbyor I did. you look at the public onclick(view v) which is at the botton of the code, before datepicker code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialize your Buttons, You have only declared them in your Activity

```
Button saveButton = null;
Button cancelButton = null;
```

Later  on you need to initialized them in `onCreate()` method as follows,

```
saveButton = (Button) findViewById ( your ID );
cancelButton = (Button) findViewById ( you ID );
```

Then you need to add OnClickListener

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

First Initialise Your `Button` using `findViewById`(//Your ID here)

Second implement `OnClickListener` for Your `Button` in order to Save the Content into the `Database`

Check Out Your `File Explorer` for your database:

1) `Windows-->ShowView-->File Explorer`

2) `data--->data--->you package Name---.databases`

3) `if Created you will see your database`

Comment: @Chloe Have you followed my answer by the way ? :)Let Me know if you still didn't find it

Answer (score 1):

Check out your database from your Eclipse by following below steps:

- `Window -> Open Perspective -> DDMS`
- Open **File Explorer** window
- Explore **(data/data/your application pacakge name/database)**** directory.
- Inside that you have your database with the name **(myDB)** you have provided.

Also initialize your buttons for the click listener also..

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     saveButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.yourID );
   cancelButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.you ID );

   saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
   cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 }
```

Comment: as mention, I HAVE DID IT! BUT CANT FIND

Comment: That means your database is not created. Have you created an instance of `AndroidOpenDbHelper` class ?

Comment: @GrIsHu, I am very much impressed :D

Comment: @Chloe As you have written your code inside button click and you have not registered any button for click listener that is why the code of your insertion in database is not working. Check out my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Goto File Explorer Windows>show view>File explorer>data>package>database name to see your database in emulator